# Error in my yacc file

Tags: compiler-construction, yacc, lex

I am trying to create a parser for certain language

Whenever I input an example it outputs "Unsuccessful Parse" and I can't seem to find what is wrong.

This is my .l file and .y file

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include "stdlib.h"
#include"y.tab.h"
FILE *fp,*yyin;
extern void yyerror(char *);
extern int line = 1;
int pos = 1;
int com= 0;
int errorcomment;
%}

/* Regular definitions */

letter           [a-zA-Z] 
digit            [0-9]
blank_str        ([\t]|" ")
identifier       {letter}({letter}|{digit})*([".""#""$""_"]?({letter}|{digit})+)?
num              ([0-9]+)|(([0-9])+"."[0-9]*)([eE]["+""-"]?[0-9]+)? 
wrongIdentifier   [a-zA-z][a-zA-Z0-9]*["#""$""_""@""^""!""%"]        
wrongNumber       ([0-9]+)({letter}|["#""$""_""@""^""!""%""+""-" "|"])+


/* Regular definitions */


%option noyywrap
%%

\n                {line++; pos = 1;}
{blank_str}       {pos +=yyleng;}


[Ii][Ff]                 {pos +=yyleng; if(com==0)return IF;}
[Ee][Ll][Ss][Ee]         {pos +=yyleng; if(com==0)return ELSE;}
[Rr][Ee][Tt][Uu][Rr][Nn] {pos +=yyleng; if(com==0)return RETURN;}
[Ww][Hh][Ii][Ll][Ee]     {pos +=yyleng; if(com==0)return WHILE;}
[Vv][Oo][Ii][Dd]         {pos +=yyleng; if(com==0)return VOID;}
[Ii][Nn][Tt]             {pos +=yyleng; if(com==0)return INT;}
[Ll][Ee][Tt]             {pos +=yyleng; if(com==0)return LET;}


{identifier}          {pos +=yyleng; if(com==0)return ID;}
{num}                 {pos +=yyleng; if(com==0)return NUM;}
{wrongIdentifier}     {pos +=yyleng; if(com==0)printf("\n**ERROR: Wrong Identifier in Line %d at %d\n\n\n", line, pos-yyleng);}
{wrongNumber}         {pos +=yyleng;; if(com==0)printf("\n**ERROR: Wrong Number in Line %d at %d\n\n\n", line, pos-yyleng);}




"+"  {pos +=yyleng; if(com==0)return ADDOP;}
"-"  {pos +=yyleng; if(com==0)return ADDOP;}
"*"  {pos +=yyleng; if(com==0)return MULOP;}
"/"  {pos +=yyleng; if(com==0)return MULOP;}
"="  {pos +=yyleng; if(com==0)return AssgOP;}
"<"  {pos +=yyleng; if(com==0)return RELOP;}
"<=" {pos +=yyleng; if(com==0)return RELOP;}
">"  {pos +=yyleng; if(com==0)return RELOP;}
">=" {pos +=yyleng; if(com==0)return RELOP;}
"==" {pos +=yyleng; if(com==0)return RELOP;}
"!=" {pos +=yyleng; if(com==0)return RELOP;}
","  {pos +=yyleng; if(com==0)return COMMA;}
";"  {pos +=yyleng; if(com==0)return Semicolon;}
"("  {pos +=yyleng; if(com==0)return Left_Brace;}
")"  {pos +=yyleng; if(com==0)return Right_Brace;}
"["  {pos +=yyleng; if(com==0)return LSquare_Bracket;}
"]"  {pos +=yyleng; if(com==0)return RSquare_Bracket;}
"{"  {pos +=yyleng; if(com==0)return LWavy_Bracket;}
"}"  {pos +=yyleng; if(com==0)return RWavy_Bracket;}
"/*" {pos +=yyleng; errorcomment = line; com=1;}
"*/" {pos +=yyleng; com=0;} 




.    {pos +=yyleng; printf("\n**ERROR : NOT IN THE ALPHABET in Line %d at %d\n\n\n", line, pos-yyleng);}


%%
```

This is .y file

```
%{

#include <stdio.h> /* C declarations used in actions */
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
extern int line;

extern FILE *yyin;
extern int yylex(void);

int yywrap()
{
return 1;
}

main()
{
yyparse();
if (yyparse()==0)
    printf("Successful Parse.\n");
else
    printf("Unsuccessful Parse.\n");

//return 0;

}

extern int yyerror (char * s) // allows for printing of an error msg
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Error at line %d : %s\n",line, s);
    return 0; 
}

%}




%token ID
%token NUM
%token LET
%token IF
%token ELSE
%token INT
%token RETURN
%token VOID
%token WHILE
%token ADDOP
%token MULOP
%token RELOP
%token AssgOP
%token Semicolon
%token COMMA
%token Left_Brace
%token Right_Brace
%token LSquare_Bracket
%token RSquare_Bracket
%token LWavy_Bracket
%token RWavy_Bracket

%nonassoc LOWER_THAN_ELSE
%nonassoc ELSE
%%



program: declaration_list ;
declaration_list: declaration_list declaration  
                | declaration 
                ;

declaration: var_declaration 
           | fun_declaration 
           ;

var_declaration: type_specifier ID Semicolon 
               | type_specifier ID LSquare_Bracket NUM RSquare_Bracket Semicolon 
               ;

type_specifier: INT 
              | VOID 
              ;

fun_declaration: type_specifier ID Left_Brace params Right_Brace compound_stmt ;

params: param_list 
      | VOID
      ;

param_list: param_list COMMA param 
          | param 
      ;

param: type_specifier ID 
     | type_specifier ID LSquare_Bracket RSquare_Bracket 
     ; 

compound_stmt: LWavy_Bracket local_declararions statement_list RWavy_Bracket ;

local_declararions:  local_declararions  var_declaration 
          | 
          ;

statement_list: statement_list statement 
          | 
          ;

statement: expression_stmt 
         | compound_stmt 
         | selection_stmt 
         | iteration_stmt 
         | return_stmt 
         ; 

expression_stmt: expression Semicolon 
           | Semicolon 
           ;

selection_stmt: IF Left_Brace expression_stmt Right_Brace statement   %prec LOWER_THAN_ELSE 
          | IF  Left_Brace expression_stmt Right_Brace statement ELSE statement 
          ;

iteration_stmt: WHILE Left_Brace expression_stmt Right_Brace statement ;

return_stmt: RETURN Semicolon 
       | RETURN expression Semicolon 
       ;

expression: LET var AssgOP expression 
          | simple_expression 
      ;

var: ID 
   | ID LSquare_Bracket expression RSquare_Bracket 
   ;
simple_expression: additive_expression RELOP additive_expression 
                 | additive_expression 
         ;

additive_expression: additive_expression ADDOP term 
           | term 
           ;

term: term MULOP factor 
    | factor 
    ; 
factor: Left_Brace expression Right_Brace 
      | var 
      | call 
      | NUM 
      ;

call: ID Left_Brace args Right_Brace ;

args: arg_list 
    | 
    ;

arg_list: arg_list COMMA expression 
    | expression                 
    ;
```

Any Help Can be appreciated it

I input a simple code  like    int x[10]; and it still doesn't work

Comment: Why all the `if (com == 0)` stuff? Never seen that before. Just return the token that got scanned. You seem to be over-thinking this.

Comment: @EJP The ifs are there, so that it doesn't generate tokens inside comments. If he just removed the `if`s, the contents of comments would not be ignored. The reason that you don't usually see this is that there are better way to handle comments (namely using start conditions or just reading a comment as a single token if the syntax allows this). The fact that there's no `if` in the `.` rule means that comments must only contain valid tokens though, which I can't imagine is intended.

Comment: @sepp2k So he should handle comments properly.

Answer (score 0):

This question has sat unanswered for months because it is poorly constructed and makes anyone work hard to answer it. You should read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for ways to make an effective question. In particular there was no attempt to **simplify** the problem. Simplifyng a problem to its essence is the nature of debugging and hence the secret of programming. How it could be simplified will become clear when I reveal the fix.
All the comments were just canards. Not relevant to the fault or its solution, but an artefact of the failure to simplify.

I have built the code , as written, and debugged it. The first thing to note is that there are *still* compilation errors. You should at least remove the errors that the compiler discovers for you before going to SO and asking for more help.

In the `lex` file (line 6) you have this:

```
extern void yyerror(char *);
```

In the `yacc` file (line 28) you have this:

```
extern int yyerror (char * s) // allows for printing of an error msg
```

As the compiler will tell you, that is a mismatched type!

Now it builds and runs with exactly the fault you describe.

The next stage to a solution requires using the debugging capability built into yacc. If you [read the yacc man page](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?yacc) you will note it has an option `-t` which will:

```
 -t      Change the preprocessor directives generated by yacc so that
         debugging statements will be incorporated in the compiled code.
```

The next step is to enable those debugging statement using the yydebug flag (the yacc file at line 17):

```
main()
{  extern int yydebug; yydebug = 1 ; /* Enable debugging */
yyparse();
if (yyparse()==0)
```

Now, when you run your code on your example(`int x[10];`) you get this output:

```
Reading a token: Now at end of input.
Reducing stack by rule 1 (line 67):
   $1 = nterm declaration_list ()
-> $$ = nterm program ()
Stack now 0
Entering state 3
Now at end of input.
Shifting token $end ()
Entering state 9
Stack now 0 3 9
Cleanup: popping token $end ()
Cleanup: popping nterm program ()
Starting parse                           <----------- **See here** ----
Entering state 0
Reading a token: Now at end of input.
Error at line 2 : syntax error
Cleanup: discarding lookahead token $end ()
Stack now 0
Unsuccessful Parse.
```

Notice the piece I flagged up for you? It says `Staring parse`. That is strange, why would it start a parse when it has **just recognised a program** and reached the end of input? That is because you told it to. You will note in the extract of the main program I just just earlier you call `yyparse()` twice. Once recognises the program and the **second one gives a syntax error** when it tries to read past the end-of-file.

You solution then, is to **remove the extra `yyparse()`**.

Just to be very clear, the yacc file (lines 16-19) now read:

```
main()
{  
/* yyparse(); - removed */
if (yyparse()==0)
```

Now that was simple wasn't it? If you'd simplified the code you might have found  it yourself. If you'd used the tools available you'd probably also found it yourself. Even if you didn't, by asking for help with simpler code you would have got an answer the same day.